# export default new object

Tags: javascript, node.js, export, module.exports

Is it guaranteed that `export default new object()`, where object is some kind of type (e.g. Date), returns the same object all the time?

```js
// date.js
export default new Date()
// foo.js
import date from './date'
// bar.js
import date from './date'
```

Can it be expected that `date` in `foo.js` and `date` in `bar.js` are equivalent. So `import date from './date'` is a singleton?

Would the above `export default new Date()` be equivalent to `module.exports = new Date()` for pre-es6 era?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will always be the same object. In any given run of a script, you can assume that the top level of a file, eg:

```
// date.js
export default new Date()
```

will run *exactly once*, and no more, if the file gets imported. Further imports of that file will result in `date.js`'s exports being importable, but will not run `date.js` again.

Comment: I'm sure you're correct, but just to clarify, would it be accurate to say that a source file imported into a given realm is guaranteed to be executed once only?

Comment: @Pointy I don't think it's guaranteed by ecma262 but maybe it's standardized somewhere else. The only reference I can find in the spec is that it says that other modules importing the same specifier might resolve to the same module instance, [here last paragraph](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-hostresolveimportedmodule). It does guarantee that any other module import on the same source will resolve to the same module.

Comment: @MinusFour yes that makes sense; I mean it kind-of has to work that way or everything would be weird.